# pandas remove the duplicated row base on same columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
    Date    Model   High     Low    Final
1   9132022 model6  4.36000  2.39   3.10
2   9132022 model4  10.92000 2.87   8.32
3   9132022 model6  4.36000  2.39   3.73
4   9132022 model6  4.36000  2.39   3.10
5   9132022 model6  4.36000  2.39   2.47

6   9142022 model6  41.3600 21.39   31.10
7   9142022 model4  110.920 21.87   81.32
8   9142022 model6  41.3600 21.39   31.73
9   9142022 model6  41.3600 21.39   31.10
10  9142022 model6  41.3600 21.39   21.47
```

If the Date and Model are the same,just keep the first record,the output should be:

```
        Date    Model   High     Low    Final
    1   9132022 model6  4.36000  2.39   3.10
    2   9132022 model4  10.92000 2.87   8.32
 

    3   9142022 model6  41.3600 21.39   31.10
    4   9142022 model4  110.920 21.87   81.32
```

Comment: This is exactly what `drop_duplicates` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so first we need to recreate OP's dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [9132022, 9132022, 9132022, 9132022, 9132022, 9142022, 9142022, 9142022, 9142022, 9142022],
                   "Model": ["model6", "model4", "model6", "model6", "model6", "model6", "model4", "model6", "model6", "model6"],
                   "High": [4.36000,10.92000,4.36000,4.36000,4.36000,41.3600,110.920,41.3600,41.3600,41.3600],
                   "Low": [2.39,2.87,2.39,2.39,2.39,21.39,21.87,21.39,21.39,21.39],
                   "Final":[3.10,8.32,3.73,3.10,2.47,31.10,81.32,31.73,31.10,21.47]
                   })
```

Then what you need to do is group by `Date` and `Model` columns, and then return the first occurence of everything by using the `first` aggregate function:

```py
df.groupby(["Date","Model"],as_index=False).first()
```

outputs:

```
0   9132022 model4  10.92   2.87    8.32
1   9132022 model6  4.36    2.39    3.10
2   9142022 model4  110.92  21.87   81.32
3   9142022 model6  41.36   21.39   31.10
```

This messes up the index a little, but if you want to keep the original index you can `df = df.reset_index()` before the grouping.

For future reference please consider providing the original dataframe (in code) so that people that want to look into it can recreate it easily, without having to manually copy & paste values.

If this solved your problem please mark the answer as solution. :)

Comment: too bad there is no `tribble` like in `tidyverse` to consume such input

Answer (score 2):

If the name of the variable for the DataFrame is `df` then:

```py
df.groupby(['Date', 'Model']).head(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to it

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date','Model'])
```

```
       Date     Model   High    Low     Final
0   9132022     model6  4.36    2.39    3.10
1   9132022     model4  10.92   2.87    8.32
5   9142022     model6  41.36   21.39   31.10
6   9142022     model4  110.92  21.87   81.32
```